# How to integrate product.html with product.twing in Opencart?

Tags: opencart

I have a file product.html and the accompanying css and js files. I need to integrate it into product.twing, how can this be done?

I found a couple of examples in Google, it showed that you just transfer the code from html to twing, but in this case I lose all the pictures and styles

Comment: If you want to embed the static product.html content you can use

 {% include 'product.html' %}

I am not clear what you mean by losing your pictures. You need to ensure the url referenced is valid

Answer (score -1):

To integrate an HTML template into an OpenCart product.twig file while preserving the styles and images, you need to make sure that the CSS and JS files are properly linked and that the image paths are updated correctly.

Here are the steps you can follow to integrate the HTML template into the product.twig file:

1. Copy the CSS and JS files: Place the CSS and JS files from the HTML template into the appropriate directories in your OpenCart theme. Usually, the CSS files are placed in the `catalog/view/theme/your_theme/stylesheet/` directory, and the JS files in the `catalog/view/theme/your_theme/javascript/` directory.
2. Update CSS and JS file links: In the product.twig file, make sure to update the CSS and JS file links to reflect the new paths. For example, if the CSS file is named `custom.css`, you would link it in the product.twig file as follows:

   ```
   <link href="{{ asset('stylesheet/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
   ```

   Similarly, for JS files, use the `asset()` function to link them.
3. Update image paths: Update the image paths in the product.twig file to point to the correct locations. If the images are stored in the `image/` directory of your OpenCart installation, you can use the `image()` function in the product.twig file to generate the correct image paths. For example:

   ```
   <img src="{{ image('product.jpg') }}" alt="Product Image">
   ```
4. Copy HTML code: Copy the relevant HTML code from your product.html file and paste it into the appropriate section of the product.twig file. You may need to modify the HTML structure to match the OpenCart template structure and ensure that the necessary OpenCart variables and functions are used.
5. Adapt and customize: Review the integrated HTML code and customize it further if needed to match the functionality and layout requirements of OpenCart.

Remember to clear your OpenCart cache and refresh the product page to see the changes.

Please note that integrating an HTML template into OpenCart may require further adjustments and modifications based on the specific structure and requirements of your OpenCart theme. It's recommended to have a good understanding of OpenCart's template system and its variables to achieve the desired integration effectively.